# how to set static ip to pc for tor

Tags: dhcp, ip, static-ip

I use tor proxy and i set the tunnel port to 192.168.1.2:9050.

I also set my router dhcp that give 192.168.1.2 to my pc

but my problem is that sometimes I use another router or my phone hotspot and they give my pc anothre ip (like 192.168.43.164/24) . I can't set their dhcp. so tor doesn't work.

Is there any way to always get the same ip ?

Or Is there any way to refer my wifi ip (something like localhost that refer to 127.0.0.1) to set in tor?

Comment: It is impossible to control what IP range/network every location you use your computer in will be assigned.  There is no way to 'always get the same IP' with private IPs or public IP addresses when you switch between multiple networks

Comment: @user.dz that won't solve their issue of getting the same IP on **multiple networks** (a different router, or a phone hotspot, with different public IPs, etc. than their home network)

Comment: @ThomasWard I didn't notice, he is referring to min of two hosts, one is used as tor proxy.

Comment: @ThomasWard ok I get that i can't get same ip on multiple networks but how can I solve my tor config.I want to use tor sockport so that i can access it on non-local network

Comment: @mohammadaghaie if you can't guarantee a static IP, then you should probably look into getting a VPS or cloud server for cheap monthly that you can run your torproxy on and then connect to that as your tor proxy relay.  However, if you cannot control the endpoint IPs for your machines in question (proxy and actual machine) then you can't really guarantee the same IP.  The only way to make your config work is to set up your tor proxy independently of the systems where you don't control the IP - such as a VPS - and then use that as your tor proxy entrypoint.

Comment: @ThomasWard you mean there is not any keyword like localhost (for exmple nonlocalhost) that always refer to non-local ip address?

Comment: @mohammadaghaie If the non-local IP keeps changing then no.  Otherwise, you can set something like Dynamic DNS on your torproxy host and use a dynamic DNS provider to set up a domain name you can refer to that gets updated regularly, but your tor proxy needs to be online all the time for that to behave, and if the tor proxy changes networks as well there will be lag/downtime before it updates fully and is available and such.